# Converting Adjacency Matrix to Abstract Simplicial Complex

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, graph, topology

I have a graph as represented by an adjacency matrix and I would like to convert that into an abstract simplicial complex (that is, a list of all vertices, edges, triangles, tetrahedrons...) in order to do some topology computations on the graph. However, I'm having some trouble getting the algorithm quite right. I looked online and couldn't find anything that quite did this.

In words, what the code does is makes a list of all edges (for example, an edge between a and b would be ab so the list would look like `[ab, bc, ad...]`. We then need to find all triangles. So, start with a random edge, say `ab` and add it to a string. Then similar to a depth-first-search, we add to a queue a list of all other edges that have either a or b in them. We try appending them to the string. If, after 3 iterations, the string is comprised of duplicates (that is, it looks like `abbcca`) then add `abc` to my list of triangles, pop the stack and try again.

Similarly, for 3 dimensions (tetrahedrons) we do something similar and look at our list of triangles `[abc, bcd, bce...]`. We take `abc` and add all triangles that share EITHER `ab`, `bc`, or `ac` to our queue and try appending those triangles to the string. If, after 4 iterations we have only duplicates then we know that there's a tetrahedron.

Keep going for as many dimensions as wanted.

But, the code is not working as desired and I'm really stuck.

Right now I'm just working in 2-dimensions and trying to get triangles and will simply add logic to handle higher later.

```
    def DFS(edges, count, node, triangles, tempTriangle):
    print(tempTriangle)
    visited, stack = set(), [node]
    tempTriangle = tempTriangle.strip(" ")
    if count > 2:
        return 
    elif len(tempTriangle) % 3 == 0 and deleteDuplicates(tempTriangle) == "":
        print("Triangle: ", oneTimeLetters(tempTriangle))
        triangles.append(oneTimeLetters(tempTriangle))
        tempTriangle = ""

    neighbors = [x for x in edges if hasIntersection(node, x) == False and strIntersection(tempTriangle, x) != x]

    for y in neighbors:
        if y not in visited:
            visited.add(y)
            tempTriangle = tempTriangle + y
            if count > 2:
                count = 0
                node = (edges - visited)[0]
                DFS(edges, 0, node, triangles, "")
            DFS(edges, count+1, y, triangles, tempTriangle)
            tempTriangle = tempTriangle[:len(tempTriangle)-2]
            visited.pop()

def deleteDuplicates(word):
    letterList = set()
    for c in word:
        if c in letterList:
            word = word.replace(c, "")
        letterList.add(c)
    return word

def oneTimeLetters(word):
    letterList = set()
    for c in word:
        if c in letterList:
            word = word.replace(c, "")
        letterList.add(c)
    return ''.join(letterList)

def hasIntersection(a, b):
        return not set(a).isdisjoint(b)

def strIntersection(s1, s2):
  out = ""
  for c in s1:
    if c in s2 and not c in out:
      out += c
  return out
```

I'm running this on the toy case of a graph with 5 vertices given by

```
Edges = ['cd', 'da', 'eb', 'cb', 'dc', 'ea', 'db', 'ac', 'ca', 'bd', 'ba', 'be', 'ad', 'bc', 'ab', 'ae']


Adjacency matrix =
 [[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
     [ 1.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
     [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
     [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
     [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Given that input it just returns an empty list and the print statement from tempTriangle gives me a long list of things

```
dc
dcae
dcaecd
dcaecb
dcaedb
dcaebc
dcaebd
dcba
dcbacd
dcea
dceacd
dceacb
dceadb
dceabc
//...abbreviated the long list
```

So, it doesn't stop when supposed to, doesn't add to the triangles list and just all around doesn't work.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your code do wrong?

Comment: Added the input/output. Thanks!

Comment: I dont see how `count` is passed into the  `AdjacencyToASC()` function initially also where is `i` defined?

Comment: The `i` came from a silly mistake before. I changed it to reflect the more accurate code and test case scenario. I call the function later on with ```AdjacencyToASC(edges, 0, edges[0], triangles, "")
print(triangles)``` where `triangles` is an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some working code. It keeps your basic idea but refines it a bit by keeping and reusing the list of shared neighbors of each simplex in the previous degree.

When finding the next degree simplices containing a simplex S, we choose a random vertex V and the subsimplex S-V. To find the neighbors of S we simply look up those of V and S-V and take the intersection. Each element N in the intersection gives a new simplex S+N.

We take advantage of set and dict containers for fast lookup, intersection and duplicate purging.

```
def find_cliques(edges, max_sz=None):
    make_strings = isinstance(next(iter(edges)), str)
    edges = {frozenset(edge) for edge in edges}
    vertices = {vertex for edge in edges for vertex in edge}
    neighbors = {vtx: frozenset(({vtx} ^ e).pop() for e in edges if vtx in e)
                 for vtx in vertices}
    if max_sz is None:
        max_sz = len(vertices) 

    simplices = [set(), vertices, edges]
    shared_neighbors = {frozenset({vtx}): nb for vtx, nb in neighbors.items()}
    for j in range(2, max_sz):
        nxt_deg = set()
        for smplx in simplices[-1]:
            # split off random vertex
            rem = set(smplx)
            rv = rem.pop()
            rem = frozenset(rem)
            # find shared neighbors
            shrd_nb = shared_neighbors[rem] & neighbors[rv]
            shared_neighbors[smplx] = shrd_nb
            # and build containing simplices
            nxt_deg.update(smplx|{vtx} for vtx in shrd_nb)
        if not nxt_deg:
            break
        simplices.append(nxt_deg)
    if make_strings:
        for j in range(2, len(simplices)):
            simplices[j] = {*map(''.join, map(sorted, simplices[j]))}
    return simplices

# demo
from itertools import combinations
edges = set(map(''.join, combinations('abcde', 2)))
random_missing_edge = edges.pop()
simplices = find_cliques(edges)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(random_missing_edge)
pprint(simplices)
```

Sample output:

```
'ae'
[set(),
 {'d', 'a', 'e', 'c', 'b'},
 {'be', 'ab', 'cd', 'bd', 'ad', 'ac', 'ce', 'bc', 'de'},
 {'bce', 'abc', 'acd', 'bcd', 'cde', 'abd', 'bde'},
 {'abcd', 'bcde'}]
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you so much!! You're the best! This is really really smart. Thanks.